# Run shell script on incoming network package

Tags: linux, networking, debian, iptables, raspberry-pi

I have a bit of a weird question. I have a setup where a Raspberry Pi (running that debian) sits next to a door in my office and is connected to the network. The idea now is that if somebody inside the network goes in a browser and tries to access 192.168.1.x:6000 (or any specific port actually) it executes a script on the Raspi that outputs a little current over the IO component and makes the door open. (We don't have a buzzer :p)

My question would now be how to do that (the running the script via network, I have the script :P ). I've looked into iptables rules and netcat but don't seem to be able to find anything that is of help to me. I hope you can give me some pointers with this. Thank you.

Comment: is the ip address that of the raspberry pi? I'm pretty sure there's similar projects floating around online - they usually use a small web server for that, and often python for controlling the IO pins

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment :p Yea the IO pins are being controled via a python script. By small web server you mean http server? Anything I could google for that? I'm really not an expert on the network side of things xD

Answer (score 0):

You can use tcpdump, it will listen for incoming packets and print one line of output if such a packet is received. So you can write a small script that will do something when tcpdump prints a line. In bash you do this with `while read line; do`, where `$line` will contain the line.

Please also look into the solution Journeyman Geek provided you in the comments, his solution to you problem may be a lot cleaner.